# Ordering real numeric quantities

Tags: numerics, expression-test

Suppose I want to have a function (call it NLess) that given two real numeric quantities, a and b, it returns True if a is smaller than b, ignoring precision. Here are some test cases:

```
NLess[3.14`1, Pi]
NLess[4.49999999999999`,4.50000000000001`]
NLess[E, Pi]
NLess[3.14159265358979323846263`22, Pi]
NLess[4.49`1, 9/2]
NLess[E, 2.782`1]
```

All of these should return True. The usual `Less` function only returns true for Less[E, Pi]:

```
Less[3.14`1, Pi]
Less[4.49999999999999`,4.50000000000001`]
Less[E, Pi]
Less[3.14159265358979323846263`22, Pi]
Less[4.49`1, 9/2]
Less[E, 2.782`1]
```

> False
>
> False
>
> True
>
> False
>
> False
>
> False

I have some code to do this, but I find it unsatisfactory.

---

*One further detail. It is acceptable to me to have both:*

```
 N[3.14`1, 3.14`100]
 N[3.14`100, 3.14`1]
```

*be false, or one or the other to be True, but it would be nice if this behavior could be controlled*

Comment: I take it that ``3.14`1`` should be treated as though it were `3.14` exactly and that that the machine precision (MP) number ``4.49999999999999` `` should be treated as `5066549580791797/2^50` if MP = `binary64` (which might depend on machine precision)? Or should MP numbers be rounded to their decimal equivalents displayed by `InputForm`?

Comment: Is this "satisfactory? `NLess[a_, b_] := Less[Rationalize[
   SetPrecision[a, Max[MachinePrecision, Precision[a]]], 0], 
  Rationalize[SetPrecision[b, Max[MachinePrecision, Precision[b]]], 
   0]]`. It actually only works because, to my surprise, `Rationalize[Pi,0]` still gives `Pi` (which is not a rational number).

Comment: @Felix Should ``NLess[0.3333333333333333`, 1/3]`` return `True`?

Comment: Indeed, the working precision must be increased beyond the provided precision. How about this? `NLess[a_, b_] := 
 Less[Rationalize[
   SetPrecision[a, Max[MachinePrecision, Precision[a]] + 1], 0], 
  Rationalize[
   SetPrecision[b, Max[MachinePrecision, Precision[b]] + 1], 0]]`

Comment: Yeah, I actually just realize that the `+1` might just work in many cases but not all. I guess it boils down to understanding systematically of why, for instance, `Rationalize[3.14`3, 0]` gives `22/7` even though it should have enough significant digits to make it `157/50`.

Comment: @Felix What about ``NLess[0.99999999999999999999999`15, 1]``? If we knew the limit on the extra precision kept by arbitrary precision numbers, you could add that to `Max[..]` instead of `1`.  I expect it's not very big.

Comment: @Michael E2 Unless the numbers are identical, then one should be smaller than the other. I don't think you need to worry about internal binary representations.

Comment: But is ``4.49999999999999` `` identical to double-precision floating-point fraction `5066549580791797/2^50` or to decimal input fraction `449999999999999/10^14`? It can't be both. And what to do about comparing it to ``4.49999999999999`15`` would seem to depend on the answer. I would have assumed it was the internal binary representation, but somehow you've made me doubt that.

Comment: @Michael E2 I'm satisfied with InputForm/FullForm representations of the numbers, but if you can incorporate the underlying machine representations of the numbers, that would be fine as well. Also, I added something to the OP about numbers that differ only in precision.

Comment: This seems to work for any numbers I could come up with so far: `NLess[a_, b_] := 
 Less[Rationalize[
   SetPrecision[a, Max[MachinePrecision, Precision[a]]*2 + 1], 0], 
  Rationalize[
   SetPrecision[b, Max[MachinePrecision, Precision[b]]*2 + 1], 0]]`.

Comment: It returns False for `NLess[Pi - 1\`10*^-22, N[Pi, 3]]` in M11. I'm looking at M10 now.

Comment: @Felix It returns False for `NLess[N[Pi, 3], Pi + 1\`10*^-33]` in M10.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm running out of ideas. However, clearly your problem boils down to converting floating point numbers to exact rationals without loss of precision. I agree with @MichaelE2 that the key is to get access to the internal binary representation of the number. Alternatively, you could try to parse the text returned by `InputForm[N[a,precision]]` to construct this kind of new `Rationalize` function.

Comment: Related: "[Is there a “normal” EqualQ function in Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4983885/590388)"

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
NLess[a_, b_, p_: 1000] := Order @@ N[{a, b}, p] == 1
```

The third (optional) parameter $p$ controls the precision used for exact numbers and numbers with precision greater than $p$.  [`Order`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Order.html) appears to ignore `` Internal`$SameQTolerance `` etc.

Comment: Mr.Wizard what does the : 1000 near the pattern do? i have never seen it before

Comment: @Alucard ``FullForm[p_: 1000]`` gives `Optional[Pattern[p, Blank[]], 1000]` so you should look at [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html)

Comment: ah got it , thank you